# How to convert a bar into an axle or pin - Using the Axel Hub with Four Bars

Tags: building, technic

I would like to utilize the Axle Hub with 4 Bars ([#48723](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=48723#T=C)) in a way that the four bars would become axles. What is the most concise way to accomplish that?

Here is a diagram of my end goal:

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here are couple of ideas. You could use pins:

[image: Using pins]

Or axles with studs on the end:

[image: Using axle with stud]

Or axle connectors and axles:

[image: Using axle connectors]

Comment: Thanks a bunch, the picture references are great here! It looks like that third option would be the most stable so I may try that first.